# My laptop has no numpad, no numlock, how can I simulate it?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Just bought a Toshiba Satellite S45t, it has no numlock!
Num pad is not writen as an option on the uiojkl keys.
I have installed Ubuntu 14.10

numlockx on, does not make any changes at all.
I have used the internal ubuntu keyboard shortcuts plus xdotool to map ctrl-alt-j for 1 etc.
That works in some progrms like libreoffice,remmina, but it does not work in calculator, chrome, etc.

xdotool does not work at all mapping ctr + alt + 7

Any other method to correctly simluate a numeric pad?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i

apt-get update

apt-get install xvkbd
```

Xvkbd is a virtual (graphical) keyboard program for X Window System.

When xvkbd is started, the image of a keyboard will be displayed on the screen.

Clicking any key on the xvkbd window will send the character to the focused window as if the key had been actually typed with the hardware keyboard.

Source: http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/

Comment: Thanks, but actually I don't wanta virtual keyboard, I want to do some mapping to my hardware keyboard. Bytheway onboard comes installed by defaut and it look way better that xvkbd.